# Powershell script that prompts user

Tags: powershell, scripting, file-manipulation

How would I go about adding a delete feature to my script that is similar to the rename one? Where it opens up the file browser and allows a user to select a file to delete? Is it possible or do I have to do it another way? I need help with option 3 please.

```
}
#now start the loop calling the function named Show-Menu
do {
    Show-Menu
    #ask the user to make a selection and read this in as a variable
    $options = Read-Host "Enter your choice"
    switc
        #Renames a folder
        '2' {
            $
            # Se = ($renamefolder -split "\\")[-1]
            # Change our path so the directories can be referenced more easily via
until ($options -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty straightforward (watch code below). Few points I'd like to note.

I've renamed a function to replicate the result of it.

If you click `Cancel` when selecting folder browser dialog in your script - it would go further. With the `do {} while ()` loop it won't :)

```
function Get-FolderPath() {  
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
 
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    do {
        $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
        $OpenFileDialog.SelectedPath
    }
    while (!($OpenFileDialog.SelectedPath))
}

#Creates a function called Show-Menu
function Show-Menu {
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'My Folder Menu'
    )
    # Clear-Host
    Write-Host "==========Choose your option============="
    Write-Host "1. Press '1' to Create a Folder"
    Write-Host "2. Press '2' to Rename a Folder"
    Write-Host "3. Press '3' to Delete a Folder"
    Write-Host "Q. Press 'Q' to exit the script"
    Write-Host "========================================="
}
#now start the loop calling the function named Show-Menu
do {
    Show-Menu
    #ask the user to make a selection and read this in as a variable
    $options = Read-Host "Enter your choice"
    switch ($options) {
        #Creates a new directory
        '1' {
            #Get parent folder path
            $parentPath = Get-FolderPath
            #Get folder name
            $folderName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input new directory name'
            #Create folder in parent path that has selected name 
            New-Item (Join-Path $parentPath $folderName) -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
        }
        #Renames a folder
        '2' {
            $renamefolder = Get-FolderPath
            $newFolderName = Read-Host 'Please enter the new name for the folder'
            # Split the path and get the last item in the array
            $oldFolderName = ($renamefolder -split "\\")[-1]
            #The same can be made using:
            #$oldFolderName = (Split-Path $renamefolder -Leaf)
    
            # Change our path so the directories can be referenced more easily via ./
            Push-Location (Join-Path $renamefolder -ChildPath ..)
            Move-Item -Path (Join-Path -Path ./ -ChildPath $oldFolderName) -Destination (Join-Path ./ -ChildPath $newFolderName)
            # Return process back to the original path
        }
        #Deletes a folder
        '3' {
            #Get folder path
            $folderToDelete = Get-FolderPath
            #Remove the item :)
            Remove-Item $folderToDelete -Verbose #-WhatIf #for testing
        }
    }
}
until ($options -eq 'q')
```

Comment: @FearThainn do you mean you want to select path, input a name and create a folder in that selected path?

Comment: Edited answer to replicate what you're looking for